# Reset MySQL Password - Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-5.7

I forgot my MySQL password.

I'm using MySQL 5.7 on a Mac.

When I use `mysql -u root` I get the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jan'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

## Things I've tried without success:

### Setting the password:

## Option 1:

```
mysql -u root
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Getting the following error after `mysql -u root`:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jan'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

## Option 2

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password NEW_PASSWORD_HERE
```

### Change root password

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/
./mysql -u root -p
> Enter password: [type old password invisibly]

use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW_PASSWORD_HERE") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

Getting the following error after `./mysql -u root -p`:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jan'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

### Resetting the password according to the MySQL manual

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

When I use `mysql` I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'jan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I also tried uninstalling MySQL from my Mac and reinstall it.

It's impossible for me to come any further without a password..

Comment: Follow the official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I tried it. Look at the heading 'Resetting the password according to the MySQL manual'. Still not working.

Comment: please give more details then "Still not working."